# Update value with put - ExpressJS, nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman

I'm new to ExpressJS, and NodeJS.
I've been trying to Google, and have went through a few different StackOverflow posts, but cannot seem to find an answer to this.

I followed a YouTube video, and created an array called users. I created get and put methods for this, which I can call upon, and then use `res.send('message')`, which works.
But whenever I try to update "name" belonging to a specific user, I constantly get the values "undefined".
I've tried:

```js
    users[req.params.id].name = req.body.name
```

as well as:

```js
    users[req.params.id].name = req.params.name   (Should be req.body.name, but still 
                                                         tried)
```

And even:

```js
    users[req.params.id]={
    name: "req.params.body"
    }                                //Which also doesn't work.
```

Weirdly enough, when I hardcode it, it works. Although Postman takes some time to load, and putting a next() just crashes it. I set it to PUT in Postman, and "localhost:3000/users/1" as a request URL(index 1 in array).

Hardcode:

```js
    users[req.params.id].name = "newSally"
```

This is my code:

```js
    const express = require('express')
    const router = express.Router()
    module.exports = router
    
    const morgan = require('morgan')
    
    router.use((req, res, next) =>{
        router.use(morgan('dev'))
        next()
    })
    
    
    router.route("/:id").get((req, res) => {
        res.send(`Getting user with the ID: ${req.params.id}, also known as: ${req.user.name} ${req.user.familyName}, and is: ${req.user.age} years old!`)
    }).put((req, res) => {
        users[id].name = req.body.name          //<--- Sets "undefined" as a new name     
                                                           
    }).delete((req, res) => {
        res.send(`Deleting user with the ID: ${req.params.id}`)
    })
    
    let users =[{name:"Kyle", familyName:"Horton", age:20}, {name:"Sally", familyName:"Myers", age:22}]
    router.param("id", (req, res, next, id) =>{
        req.user = users[id]
        next()
    })
```

Thank you!

EDIT:
Tried parsing it to int (let index = parseInt(req.params.id)), (let index = +req.params.id), as well as using the body-parser middleware, but I none of them seems to work, for some unknown reason.
At this point, I'm suspecting that I'm doing something wrong with Postman, and that it's sending out "undefined". It also seems to stay at "sending request" even after Webstorm confirmed(res.send('msg)) that it went past that code.

I put it as a PUT request, and "localhost:3000/users/1" in the request URL, and in the params, I put "key" to "name" and "value" to "newSally". After that I press the blue "Send" button.

I'm going to assume that it isn't code related, but has something to do with Postman. Thank you for your help :) @Nenad Milosavljevic, @Liki, @Georges Feungap

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add data in the `Params` section in Postman, that is available in the `req.query` object on the server. So, change your code to use `req.query` instead of `req.body`.

```js
users[req.params.id].name = req.query.name;
```

If you want data to be available in `req.body`, you should add it in the `Body` section in Postman.

Comment: Aah, got it to work :) Thank you, @Nenad Milosavljevic.

Answer (score 2):

Try using body-parser middleware
Check it out here: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html
add this block of code below instantiation of express

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do this:

```
let index = +req.params.id;
```